# I want to display the value edited by user in <apex:outputfield> (inline editing is enabled) in an alert when a user clicks on a link

Tags: force.com

I am using this code:

```
  <apex:page standardController="Account">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
      var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
     $j(document).ready(function() {
          $j('.wrapperClass :hidden').change(function(e) {
          var value= jQuery.trim(jQuery("[id$=outputfield]").val());
              alert('input was changed');
              alert(jQuery.trim(jQuery("[id$=outputfield1]")));
             // alert(jQuery("[id$=transaction_output]").html(value););
          });
      });  
  </script>

  <script>
  function myfunction()
  {
      //id='j_id0_j_id2_j_id3_j_id5_j_id6_outputfield1_ilecell';
      id='outputfield';
       Value = document.getElementById(id); 

      alert("new value"+Value.val() );
  }
  </script>

  <apex:form >
      <apex:pageBlock >
          <apex:inlineEditSupport >
              <apex:pageBlockSection title="Account Fields">
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="wrapperClass">
                      <apex:outputLabel id="outputfield" value="Account Name"/>
                      <apex:outputField id="outputfield1" value="{!Account.Name}"/>

                  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                  <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="wrapperClass">
                      <!--<apex:inputTextarea value="{!Account.Name}"/>-->
                      <apex:outputLabel value="Account text"></apex:outputLabel>
                      <apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}"></apex:outputText>
                  </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

              </apex:pageBlockSection>
          </apex:inlineEditSupport>
          <apex:commandLink value="click me" onclick="myfunction()"/>
      </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

With the help of this code I was able to capture the change event, but I want to capture the changed value, i.e., the value entered by a user to edit the field should be captured on clicking on a link displayed in an alert.

Comment: Welcome to the site! To get help you should explain exactly what the problem is, what you've tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: with the help of this code i was able to capture the change event but i want to capture the changed value ie the value entered by user to edit the field on click on a link and to display it in an alert

Comment: I know you can't edit right now so I've tagged that onto your question for you!

Answer (score 3):

From a quick check `apex:outputField` as resolved as a set of HTML elements and the value of the field is found between a `span` tag.

You could try something like this:

```
alert($j("span[id$=outputfield1]").text());
```